# What does the value after TIMESTAMP in a column definition mean?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I created a few MySQL tables via phpMyAdmin. Then I noticed that in table definitions some `TIMESTAMP` columns have a value attached:

```
timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```

What does it mean and what value should I use?

Comment: What does the manual say about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value after the type defines the fractional seconds part. To quote the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html):

> MySQL 8.0 has fractional seconds support for [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html), [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), and
>   [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision:
>
> To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the syntax ***type_name(fsp)***, where ***type_name*** is [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html), [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), or
>   [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), and ***fsp*** is the fractional seconds precision. For example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (t TIME(3), dt DATETIME(6));
> ```
>
> The ***fsp*** value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0
>   signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default
>   precision is 0. (This differs from the standard SQL default of 6, for
>   compatibility with previous MySQL versions.)

Therefore, to define a timestamp column with sub-second precision, you **must** specify a nonzero value.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is for fractional second precision, see the reference manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

MySQL 8.0 has fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision